# Stuck on infinite if loop

Tags: c#

I am working on a c# console dice sim lab for my class in Visual Studio 2015. I broke my program to three if loops depending on the user's response. I have one dedicated as a do while loop if the user doesn't input a valid response. I am stuck in that loop for some reason and can't get out. On top of that, since it's to tell the user to input a valid response, it's the first if statement. Because of that, even if I input "y", "Y", "n", or "N" it still initializes. Here is the part in question.

```
        // get response from user
        response = ReadLine();

        // loop starts if user does not reply with valid response in order to retrieve a valid response
        if (response != "N" || response != "Y" || response != "n" || response != "y")
        {
            do
            {
                WriteLine("Please reply with Y or N");
                response = ReadLine();
            }
            while (response != "N" || response != "Y" || response != "n" || response != "y");
        }
```

I am using the or operator, so I don't understand why it's looping the way it is.

Comment: You can also narrow this down a bit by using `response.ToUpper != "Y" && response.ToUpper != "N"`. That way you won't have to compare to the lower case. (You can also do the reverse with `.ToLower`)

Comment: Did you know that you can put `while` at the beginning of the loop? You wouldn't need the `if` block. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
response != "N" || response != "Y" || response != "n" || response != "y"
```

should be

```
response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y"
```

Because you should quit the loop if you hit one of the valid responses

Answer (score 1):

You need to use && instead of ||

```
response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y"
```

Answer (score 1):

The immediate cause of the misbehaivour is wrong boolean operator, you want `&&` insetead of `||`;
you can also combine `if` and `do..while` into `while..do`:

```
response = Console.ReadLine();

while (response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y") {
  WriteLine("Please reply with Y or N");
  response = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

the next step is to put all the possible responses into a collection:

```
  Dictionary<String, Boolean> expectedResponses = new Dictionary<String, Boolean>() {
    {"Y", true},
    {"y", true},
    {"N", false},
    {"n", false},
  };

  ...

  response = Console.ReadLine();

  while (!expectedResponses.ContainsKey(response)) {
    WriteLine("Please reply with Y or N");
    response = Console.ReadLine();
  }
  ...
  if (expectedResponses[response]) {
    // user said "yes"
  }
  else {
    // user said "no"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this,try to use && instead of ||.

```
    response = ReadLine();

    // loop starts if user does not reply with valid response in order to retrieve a valid response
    if (response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y")
    {
        do
        {
            WriteLine("Please reply with Y or N");
            response = ReadLine();
        }
        while (response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If its hard to imagine

```
response != "N" || response != "Y" || response != "n" || response != "y"
```

Use DeMorgan's law to expand. replace `!=` with `==`. and `||` with `&&`. put a `!` before expression.

```
!(response == "N" && response == "Y" && response == "n" && response == "y")
```

Now you see the response must be equal to `N` and `Y` and `n` and `y` at the same time. Thus its always false statement and negation before it makes it always true.

So now you understand you should put OR instead of AND. then use demorgan law to simplify again.

```
!(response == "N" || response == "Y" || response == "n" || response == "y") <=>
response != "N" && response != "Y" && response != "n" && response != "y"
```